# Kendo UI Angular 2 Components on build machine

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I need to do a build with Kendo Angular 2 components. Locally I do the command line login as specified in the installation guide http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#installation.

Any suggestions on how to do the same on a build machine?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There is similar question to this issue - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/188. Maybe you can raise your question there too.